# Possible to grant access to my server without connecting by VPN?

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server

I have a source control server that is part of my company's internal network.  Currently if I want to do something with my source control, I need to make a VPN connection before I do anything.  Is there any way to grant my computer access without creating a VPN connection every time?

I was able to setup communication between an OS X machine and a linux server using SSH.  Is there something comparable for windows?

Comment: Is the server Windows, or your machine? You can use PuTTY for ssh on a Windows machine.

Comment: Both are windows. So are you saying i could use SSH to get access to my source control server without connecting to my VPN?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this using [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com). I know it makes some people nervous to have a service like this on your server.  But it uses 128bit encryption and you can set your password to as complex as you would like.  Additionally you can configure white and black lists for further security.  This was a great option for me because it gave me access from my phone, tablet and PC's.  Teamviewer runs on port 80 so it blasts through firewalls and gives you total access to the machine it is on.